# Porting from MS Access

Tags: mysql, linux, ms-access, postgresql

I've recently been given a MS Access .mdb database file and asked to make it usable in a Linux system.  What I'm looking for is a way to convert the Access database to an open-source database such as MySQL or PostGres.

I don't have MS Office, and it's a one-time project for a volunteer organization so I don't want to spend money if it's avoidable.  I'm running Vista x64, and have a Linux virtualbox, so something usable in either one will be good.

Comment: I know it's a losing battle, but:

You don't have an MS Access MDB, but a Jet MDB. Someone may have created it with Access, but if it's just data tables, all you're going to be using is Jet, not the Access application part of the MDB.

Comment: Jet has been deprecated therefore it should *only* be used on conjuction with a legacy MS Access application (I say 'legacy' because surely new projects should be in Access2007). I think "MS Access .mdb database file" describes it with little room for ambiguity :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the [MySQL Migration Toolkit](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/migration-toolkit/en/index.html) and it worked very well for tables, even creating a reusable script. It is free and simple to use.

This toolkit is now EOL and the [MySQL Workbench 5.2](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/) replaces it.

Unfortunately, it falls over with "A problem caused the program to stop working correctly" when I try it with MS Access on my system. At the last step, of course. (Jan 16 2013)

Comment: Unfortunately, MySQL Workbench currently does not support migrating Access databases. The previous MySQL Migration Toolkit may have done it, but MySQL Workbench cannot (at least as of v5.2.47, the version I just tested). Attempting to migrate an .accdb via an ACE ODBC connection failed when trying to reverse engineer the schema, and attempting to migrate an .mdb via a Jet ODBC connection crashed MySQL Workbench altogether.

Comment: @GordThompson This question is dated '09. In '09 the Toolkit worked very well.

Comment: True, but your answer was edited 2013-01-16 (and again just now), and a recent similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15608180/exporting-ms-access-databse-to-mysql) was closed as a duplicate and referred to this one. So, I thought that a comment was appropriate when I found that MySQL Workbench couldn't do the job.

Comment: When I edited as a warning, I should have included my own experience, as I did on LessThanDot, I guess, but it seemed too narrow a test, given my set-up at the time.

Answer (score 3):

Forunately you don't need MS Access to get data out of an Access database. While there are tools like MDBTools that will read .mdb files on Linux, I've found them to be unstable for larger, more complicated databases. The best way is to use ADO or ODBC on Windows to export the data from the .mdb database into a format you can import somewhere else (like csv).

I've had good luck using [DBI with Ruby](http://ruby-dbi.rubyforge.org/), or using [ADO in a Ruby script](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/06/using-ruby-ado-to-work-with-ms-access.html).

Answer (score 2):

Following links may be useful for you.

MySQL:

[access migrate](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/access-migrate.html)

[read.php?65,27115,27115](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?65,27115,27115)

PostgreSQL:

[Microsoft Access to PostgreSQL Conversion](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access_to_PostgreSQL_Conversion)

[Converting from other Databases to PostgreSQL](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL)

Answer (score 1):

Either MySQL or Postgres will work fine as a replacement data store for your access data.  If your Access database contains Forms or Reports there really isn't a direct replacement in Open Source, and you'll either need to retain the Access front end and access the data using ODBC drivers, or code a new series of Forms or Reports in PHP or your favorite web scripting language.

Comment: http://www.kexi-project.org/  aims to be a free, open-source Microsoft Access for Linux.  Like you, I doubt that the forms/reports would work exactly the same though.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem now, and found this freeware to be exactly what I needed: http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php

It extracted everything from the MDB file generated an SQL file I imported directly into my MySQL server.

Comment: When you say "everything from the MDB file" you mean "the tables and their data only." MDB files can include a lot more than data tables.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I mean the tables and their data only, which was what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to the process

1) convert from Access database to scripts, there are some [good options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/374659/tool-to-convert-ms-access-database-to-sql-script) although you may need Access and potentially Sql Server too, to do this

2) Pick your target database - MySql would seem like a good fit, run it up on Linux or Windows and run the ddl and data in from the scripts.

Not sure how you can do this without Access though, do you have any idea what the schema looks like? If you do run into probs I could help out with step 1, but I don't have a Linux install at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

i beg to differ: there is no need to use external tools or costly middleware.  the simplest, cleanest, cheapest, fastest, safest (did i say BEST?) solution is using ODBC and integrating fully.