# Migrate MS Access to MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, ms-access

I'm getting data as an Access file.

My application uses MySQL/Java. I'd like to parse the Access data, and stick it in MySQL.

Is there a Java tool that will help me do this?

Comment: This similar question may be of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580593/porting-from-ms-access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MDB Tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mdbtools/) is a set of open source libraries and utilities to facilitate exporting data from MS Access databases (mdb files) without using the Microsoft DLLs. Thus non Windows OSs can read the data.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a one time conversion just use MS-Access, link to your MySQL database tables and use update queries to transfer the data.

If your app needs to import Access data into MySQL on a continuing basis you could connect to Access via ODBC and then have your app write the data to MySQL.

Comment: this will be a continuing effort, to be done maybe monthly. i saw a library called "Jackcess", it says it reads mdb files, that way I do not need to actually have an Access db running. Ever hear of Jackcess?

Comment: One thing that I was surprised to discover recently is that with an ODBC DSN defined, you can export an Access table to the DSN. This is a great way to move whole tables from Access into an ODBC database like MySQL.