# Open source tool for MS SQL to SQL data migration (different schemas)

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

I am working on a project to migrate databases from MS-SQL Server to MySQL and looking for open-source libraries or tools that would make my job easier, provided that the source and destination DBs wouldn't be the same. (The migration is not just a replication as it involves different schemas for both the source and destination databases.) I searched for the available tools and found these:

1. [jTDS](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/)
2. Microsoft JDBC 4.0
3. [MDB tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mdbtools/) ([Migrate MS Access to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434493/migrate-ms-access-to-mysql))

I am planning to run a batch job and use jTDS library to read the data from MS-SQL Server and then dumping them in MySQL. Is this the best way to go about it? It would be helpful if one could direct me towards a good tool and the good way to handle this.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend a tool, library or favorite off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had extremely good experiences with the SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL, this was going from MySQL to SQL Server.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28764

But for MySQL I believe the URL you want is:
http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/guide-to-migrating-from-sql-server-to-mysql/

Comment: I guess MySQl Workbench has neat tools to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you. The white paper helped.